# Cycle detection

Tags: python, algorithm

This is a function to detect cycles in a back-trace. For example a cycle `('b', 'c', 'd')` proceeded with `'a'` could be:

> ```
> >>> __cycles_detection(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
> (('b', 'c', 'd'),)
> ```

Args - funs (List[str]): functions list

Returns - list: the different cycles present in the back-trace

Can this algorithm be improved?

```
def __cycles_detection(funs):
    positions = {}
    for i in range(len(funs)):
        fun = funs[i]
        if fun in positions:
            positions[fun].append(i)
        else:
            positions[fun] = [i]

    lengths = {}
    for k, v in positions.items():
        if len(v) >= 2:
            l = v[1] - v[0]
            good = True
            for i in range(2, len(v)):
                if v[i] - v[i - 1] != l:
                    good = False
                    break
            if good:
                if l in lengths:
                    lengths[l].append((k, v))
                else:
                    lengths[l] = [(k, v)]

    cycles = []
    for k, v in lengths.items():
        l = sorted(v, key=lambda x: x[1][0])
        pat = []
        container = [l[0][0]]
        pos = l[0][1][0]
        for i in range(1, len(l)):
            _pos = l[i][1][0]
            if _pos == pos + 1:
                container.append(l[i][0])
                pos = _pos
            else:
                pat.append(tuple(container))
                container = [l[i][0]]
                pos = _pos

        pat.append(tuple(container))
        cycles += pat

    cycles = tuple(cycles)

    return cycles
```

Comment: Could you please post a simple usage example ?

Comment: One of the reasons this is hard to review is that you don't clarify what things are doing and your variables/inline documentation do not help.

Comment: I agree with enderland here, do you have example use cases and their output to clarify what you're doing?

Comment: I expanded the very small example input you gave us, "This is a function to detect cycles in a back-trace [a,b,c,d,b,c,d,b,c,d...]". Feel free to edit my changes, and if you could add some more cycles it would be appreciated. Your word definition of this algorithm seems to want `__cycles_detection([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2])` to output `((1, 2, 3), (1, 2))` rather than `((3,),)`.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, there isn't a single solution to find consecutive repetitions (cycles) in a sequence.

Here is an algorithm to find all repetition in a sequence.

```
def cycles_detection(funs):
    # Bigger cycle size first
    for size in reversed(range(2, 1 + len(funs) // 2)):
        # Find all consecutive sequences of size `size`
        for start in range(size):
            # Split the list by slices of size `size`, starting at position `start`
            end = size * ((len(funs) - start) // size) + start
            sequences = [tuple(funs[i:i + size]) for i in range(start, end, size)]
            sequences = filter(None, [tuple(funs[:start])] + sequences + [tuple(funs[end:])])

            # Init repetition to 1 then calculate consecutive repetitions
            groups = [(seq, 1) for seq in sequences]
            packing = [groups.pop(0)]
            while groups:
                prev_grp = packing[-1]
                next_grp = groups.pop(0)
                if prev_grp[0] == next_grp[0]:
                    packing[-1] = (prev_grp[0], prev_grp[1] + next_grp[1])
                else:
                    packing.append(next_grp)

            # has cycle if any repetition is greater than 2
            has_cycle = any(grp[1] > 1 for grp in packing)
            if has_cycle:
                print(packing)
```

With the following sequence, you'll have 3 possible solutions:

```
cycles_detection(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a'])
```

You'll get:

```
[(('a', 'b', 'c'), 1), (('d', 'b', 'c'), 2), (('d', 'a'), 1)]
[(('a',), 1), (('b', 'c', 'd'), 3), (('a',), 1)]
[(('a', 'b'), 1), (('c', 'd', 'b'), 2), (('c', 'd', 'a'), 1)]
```

Each list has tuple of the form `(sequence, repetition)`, where:

- `sequence` is a sub-sequence in `funs` (repeated or not),
- `repetition` is the number of occurence of consecutive sequences.

The question is: How to find the best result? Is it the longest repeated sequence, or the most repeated sequence?